# Setting the GroupStyle.Panel of a ListView on Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1, groupstyle, itemspaneltemplate

I'm trying to create a `ListView` with grouping where the elements in each group are shown horizontally (as a scrollable content). No matter what I tried with the `GroupStyle.Panel` of the `ListView` it doesn't seem to have any effect on the list.

Here is how my XAML looks:

```
  <ListView x:Name="itemListView"
            Padding="10"                
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="False"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listItemTemplate}">
     <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
           <GroupStyle.Panel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <ItemsWrapGrid ItemWidth="144" Orientation="Horizontal" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </GroupStyle.Panel>
           <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayTitle}" 
                               Margin="0,10,0,5"
                               Foreground="Black"
                               Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" 
                               TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                 </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
           </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
     </ListView.GroupStyle>
  </ListView>
```

Where

```
<Page.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="listItemTemplate">
      <Grid Width="144" Margin="5">
         <!-- details -->
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

The following image shows on the left the actual result I get, and on the right what I want to have.

[image]

I tried using a `ItemsWrapGrid` with different properties, I tried a `StackPanel` and even an `VariableSizedWrapGrid`, but nothing changed in the way the list items are displayed.

How can this be done?

Comment: doesn't windows phone have a stackpanel '

Comment: Yes, and? You're too vague.

Comment: StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"

Comment: I've tried much harder than that. If that worked (I mentioned in the last paragraph that I tried that, but you probably did not pay attention) I would not have asked this on SO.

Comment: Check [my sample](http://1drv.ms/1xY1aPQ). It looks like if `ListView.ItemsPanel`contains `ItemsStackPanel` then `GroupStyle.Panel` is ignored...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@kubakista was right about

> It looks like if ListView.ItemsPanel contains ItemsStackPanel then
>   GroupStyle.Panel is ignored...

However, changing this won't solve your problem as -

1. The scrolling becomes a bit laggy.
2. There is no horizontal scrolling.
3. The `ListView` loses virtualization.
4. The nice group header rolling up animation is gone.

---

Here is an alternative without changing the structure of the `ListView` itself but a little bit modification in your data structure.

The idea is, treat each horizontal list of rectangles under a group as *one collection item* on the UI.

This means, each group in the `ListView` will only have one child, which is actually a collection of rectangles that will be presented in an horizontal scrollable `ItemsControl`.

So, assume you have some collection of type `ObservableCollection<Item>` as the `CollectionViewSource`, the `Item` will now become type of `<ObservableCollection<Item>>` in order to hold the collection of rectangles. Therefore, the type of the collection will need to be updated to something like `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Item>>`.

Inside the `ListView`'s `ItemTemplate`, you will need to create a horizontally scrolling `ScrollViewer` and put an `ItemsControl` inside. Make sure you have set the latter's `ItemsSource` to `{Binding}`.

To enable horizontal swiping, you will need to disable the *tilt* effect by editing the default style of `ListViewItem` and commenting out the following code.

```
<!--
<VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="Normal">
        <Storyboard>
            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualTransition>
</VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
<VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer"/>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
-->
```

I have attached a working sample project [here](http://1drv.ms/13C0ZMr) as well as a screenshot shown below.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you have any idea why `ListView.ItemsPanel` influences `GroupStyle.Panel`?

Comment: @kubakista, I am just guessing here - before win8.1, `ListView`'s default `ItemsPanel` was `VirtualizingStackPanel` which doesn't virtualize when grouping is enabled. So in 8.1 they introduced this new `ItemsStackPanel` which also does virtualization for grouped data. However, when they implemented the virtualization logic, they must have only taken vertically stacked data (under each group) into consideration. So it always assumes the grouped data flows *down* and this might have affected the `Panel` of the `GroupStyle`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why a collection of collections is needed here, but it does work. The source of the listview is a collection of `Group`s, and each group has a collection of collections of `Item`s. I don't fully understand why was that necessary, and a simple collection of items in the group did not work, but I'm glad to award you the bounty points.

Comment: Thanks, let me try to explain the logic a little bit clearer. A simple collection won't give you a vertically stacked grouped list with horizontal scrollable data - this was the problem you were having. My solution is, still keep the `ListView` displaying data vertically, but each item will have an inner collection which is bound to a horizontally stacked `ItemsControl` (take a look at the `ItemsControl` inside the `ListView`'s data template). Doing this will require a collection of collections as each item will have another collection to populate the `ItemsControl`. Make more sense?

Comment: @JustinXL, the link you provided with the sample project isn't working for me, do you have an updated link? Thanks

Comment: @JustinXL, the link you provided with the sample project cannot open ?It shows "This Link doesn't work anymore". Can u share the code to work on the thing which i need.  Thanks

Comment: @Anbarasi it's still there. Log in with your Microsoft account.

Comment: @JustinXL, I login through my Microsoft account but i didn't get code

Comment: @JustinXL Please do some needy i can't get the solution