# Horizontal scroll GridView Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I have the following XAML file. I am trying to make my images to scroll horizontal. 
It doesn't work, what might be wrong?

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="SampleDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapGrid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <Image x:Name="templateImage" Source="{Binding ItemImage}" />
            </GridView>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Use a listView instead of a wrap panel. MOre info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334981/windows-8-listview-with-horizontal-item-flow

Comment: I found a nice solution here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611135/setting-the-groupstyle-panel-of-a-listview-on-windows-phone