# StackPanel within ItemsControl: Netflix poster style

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml

I would like to have a layout like Netflix when showing the movie posters:

### Category

Poster1 Poster2 Poster3

### Category 2

Poster1 Poster2 Poster3

I came up with this:

```
<ItemsControl Name="dataControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Width="100" Height="50" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Key}"></TextBlock>
                    <ItemsControl Name="dataControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Button Content="{Binding MovieName}" Width="100" Height="100"/>                                        
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

It's bound to a Dictionary that's why you have Key and Value as bindings for the controls. Sadly, the end result is this:

[image: Wrongly aligned posters]

**Note that the "movie posters" instead of being aligned horizontally, they are aligned vertically.**

It seems to create a stack of one item per "row", but I don't know how to tell it to create a one horizontal stack for all the related items.

This is the source:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Movie>> Source;
```

And this is the Movie class:

```
public class Movie
{
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
}
```

And the control is binded this way:

```
dataControl.ItemsSource = Source;
```

Comment: My answer in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611135/setting-the-groupstyle-panel-of-a-listview-on-windows-phone) might help, although it's in WP8.1, the concept is similar. What you do currently will struggle when there's a lot of data as ItemsControl doesn't support virtualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align the "movie posters" horizontally, you need to change the [ItemsPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemsPanel) like the following.

```
<ItemsControl Name="dataControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding MovieName}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

[ItemsPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemsPanel) is used to defines the panel to use for the layout of the items. The default value for the [ItemsControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol) is an [ItemsPanelTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemspaneltemplate) that specifies a [StackPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel). And for [StackPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel), it's [Orientation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_StackPanel_Orientation) is set to **Vertical** by default. That's why your items are aligned vertically.

The `StackPanel` under [DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate) controls the layout inside each item, not the layout of items inside `ItemsControl`. So setting its `Orientation` to `Horizontal` won't work. And as you only have one `Button` for each item, you can just comment out the `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is right now, you are telling each button to be inside it's own horizontally aligned `StackPanel`. You need to contain all the buttons inside one horizontal `StackPanel`. Try doing

```
<TextBlock Width="100" Height="50" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Key}"></TextBlock>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ItemsControl Name="dataControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                      <Button Content="{Binding MovieName}" Width="100" Height="100"/>                                        
                  </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Sadly the result is the same, I edited the question adding more info.